# Linker errors on library built using CMake

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I am pretty new to CMake and tried to write a simple static library that does some image manipulation using Qt4.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(timage)

find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
)
add_library(
    timage
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/timage.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
    timage
    ${QT_LIBRARIES}
)
```

I can configure, and generate it, and it even successfully builds `libtimage.a`. Now I want to include it into my main project, and here is where the trouble begins.

I started off with some unit tests, but already I get linker errors (`undefined reference` for every single function call of the `TImage` class). I built my unit tests with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -I../include -L../bin -ltimage -o test spec.cpp`

I personally do not see the difference between what I am doing to the [beginner's tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) besides the Qt4 work. I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint in the right direction here.

**Update**
I just found out that if I build my test with this CMake file:

```
link_directories(
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
)
add_definitions("-std=c++11")
add_executable(
    test
    spec.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
    test
    timage
)
```

Everything works just as expected. I am currently trying to find out what CMake is doing that I am not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that libtimage.a is probably not in `../bin`, but will by default be in `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}` - your build directory.

In your g++ command, you're adding `../bin` to your libraries search paths, but you need to be adding wherever `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}` is.

This is achieved in your second CMakeLists file in the [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command%3alink_directories) command.  However, it's generally better to avoid using this command (the documentation explains why).

If `timage` is available in your test's CMakeLists.txt as a CMake target, then there's no need to use `link_directories` - CMake already knows where to find the built library and will pass the appropriate `-L` flags automatically.  By "CMake target" I mean it's defined in that file or a parent CMakeLists.txt using the `add_library` command.

If `timage` isn't an actual CMake target in the test CMakeLists.txt (i.e. it's a totally separate project which isn't invoked from a common parent CMakeLists.txt), then you have a couple of options.

You can [`export`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command%3aexport) your `timage` project so that the test project can import it using [`include`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command%3ainclude), or you can build the library separately, and then have the test find it using [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command%3afind_library).  This will yield the full path to libtimage.a if it's found.

All of these options would avoid you having to use `link_directories`.

Another point is that you can see exactly what build command CMake is invoking by doing

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

so when you build your test, you can compare the CMake-generated command to your own.